# How many leaps must the greyhound take to catch the hare? Task from the Elements of Algebra by L. Euler

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A hare is 50 leaps before a greyhound, and takes 4 leaps to the greyhound’s 3; but two of the greyhound’s leaps are as much as three of the hare’s.

My solution was $4(l + 50) = 3*\frac32l$. But after calculating the answer doesn't seem to be right. I can't understand what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

The rabbit jumps $j_r$ ft in a leap.
The dog jumps $j_d$ ft in a leap.
$2j_d = 3j_r\ $.

The dog runs at 3j_d per unit time.
The rabbit runs at 4j_r per unit time

The dog starts at d(0) = 0.
The rabbit starts at $r(0) = d(0) + 50j_r. $

$d(t) = 0 + 3j_dt.$
$r(t) = 50j_r + 4j_rt.$
Solve $d(t) = r(t)\ $ for t.
How far did the dog run to catch up with the rabbit?
How many leaps did the dog make?

But alas, at the last moment, the rabbit ran into a rabbit hole.
The dog ran after the rabbit into the hole and got stuck.
The rabbit ran out the rabbit hole at the other side of the borrow.
The dog had to dig himself out.  The rabbit had to make repairs.